# How do I get the contents of an Array to reflect in my template?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, cursor

My **return db.Collection.find().fetch()** cursor reflects all the elements correctly in the template, apart from the elements within an array.

How do I also get the contents of the Array to reflect in my template?

Following below are the  **db.Collection.find().fetch()** results as seen in the browser console.

```
_id: "CJiuk6jjFEBLDQrQc"
postedDate: Wed Feb 15 2017 15:10:50 GMT+0300 (EAT)
descriptions: "Clothes"
viewStatisticsArray: Array[1]
```

Find below the **viewStatisticsArray: Array[1]** elements when expanded in the console.

```
0: Object
nrOfViews: 3096
statsDate: "Tue Mar 07 2017 14:10:56 GMT+0300 (EAT)"
```

And my template function:

```
  'list': function(){
        return buyList.find({}).fetch();
    }
```

Find below the results in my template:

```
{{#each list}}
Posted Date: {{postedDate}} displays: Wed Feb 15 2017 15:10:50 GMT+0300 (EAT)
Description: {{descriptions}} displays: Clothes
View Stats: {{viewStatisticsArray.nrOfViews}}  {{viewStatisticsArray.statsDate}} FAILS to DISPLAY ANYTHING

{{/each}}
```

How do I correctly access elements of the `viewStatisticsArray` array?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: have you tried iterating over viewStatisticsArray

Comment: @collision yes, I have tried that without success...

Comment: a JS array does not have a field called "nrOfViews". can you show your code where you did iterate over the array? also, why are you doing a fetch() in your helper instead of returning the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{#each items}}
    <div>{{postedDate}}</div>
    <div>{{description}}</div>
    <div>
    {{#each viewStatisticsArray}}
        {{nrOfViews}}
        {{statsDate}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

@SirBT not sure how you did your iteration, but the above should surely work. If not the only reason may be `viewStatisticsArray` is not being sent by your publish function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to call a helper to access the array in whichever way you want.
If you are just trying to get a string:

```
View Stats: {{getStats viewStatisticsArray}}
```

js:

```
  'getStats': function(array){
        return array[0].nrOfViews + " " + array[0].statsDate;
    }
```

(Write two helpers if you need them separately.) You could also alter the cursor on the server end with a [server transform](https://github.com/maximummeteor/server-transform).

```
Meteor.publishTransformed('subName', function () {
   return db.Collection.find({}) 
     .serverTransform({
          statsObj : function(item){
              return item.viewStatisticsArray[0]
          }
     }
});
```

Now you have essentially turned the array into an object and can call it the way you did in the template `statsObj.nrOfView`s and `statsObj.statsDate`.